# Convergence of sum of normal random variables with variance $\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to using Kolmogorov's 3 series to show that if

$$
X_i \quad iid \sim N(0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} )
$$

Does

$$
\sum_i^\infty X_i \quad \text{converge?}
$$

Given that the sum of the variances $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{i^\frac{1}{2}}$ diverges, I'm thinking no it doesn't converge.

Is there a way to show this using Kolmogorov's 3 series?

(Amongst other things), I've tried

$$
P(|X_i| > A) = 2 \int_A^\infty i^{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{i^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2} x^2} dx
$$

take $y = i^{1/4}x$

$$
P(|X_i|>A)= 2 \int_{Ai^{1/4}}^\infty  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} dy
$$

But I can't see how this would imply that $\sum P(|X_i|>A) \to \infty$

I realize that I can solve this using convergence with characteristic functions, but it was a practice problem in the Kolmogorov 3 series section, but I just can't see how this applies.

Comment: I think you may have more chance in showing that $\sum\mathrm{Var}(|X_i|\mathbf 1_{\{|X_i|\le A\}})$ diverges. The tail $P(|X_n|>A)$ is of order $\mathrm e^{-A\sqrt n/2}\,n^{-\frac14}$ which decays too fast…

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you very much!